# Filtering a list based on another list - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two `IEnumerable` lists.

I want to populate values into the second list based upon the results in the first.

The first `IEnumerable` list is populated like this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedList =
CategoryServices.GetAttributesByCategoryID(categoryID); // it returns selected attributes for a particular category
```

I have a function to get all attributes. Now I want to get another list which contains all other attributes (ie, the items not present in selectedList). I tried this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> available =
CategoryServices.GetAllAttributes().Where(a => !selectedList.Contains(a));
```

But its not filtering. I am getting all attributes... Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure selectdList is NOT empty in the moment of second query?

Comment: Does `GetAllAttributes()` return new object every time you call it? Does `SelectListItem` implement `IEquatable`?

Comment: Once you've resolved those problems, [I recommend using `Except(other)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) instead of `Where(a => !other.Contains(a))`.  It supports using a custom `IEqualityComparer`, so that could be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `SelectListItem` class implements [`IEquatable<SelectListItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) so the `Contains()` method has a proper means for determining equality of instances.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

IEnumerable<int> aOnlyNumbers = numbersA.Except(numbersB);

Console.WriteLine("Numbers in first array but not second array:");
foreach (var n in aOnlyNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Result

Numbers in first array but not second array:
0
2
4
6
9

Answer (score 0):

`GetAllAttributes()` will probably get you a new round of objects, they will not be the same as those returned by `GetAttributesByCategoryID(...)`. You need to compare something better than object references.

You can implement `System.IEquatable<T>` to change the [default comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx).